# Reading text files located on LINUX server and updating the tables in SQL Server Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, linux, stored-procedures

I know we can write a Stored Procedure/Bulk Insert to read the files that are located on the same Windows Server as SQL Server and update the database but not sure how to do it when the files are present in LINUX.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can access those files through some network file share, SSIS would likely be the tool to use. If It's just a 1-time or ad-hoc occurrence, the SQL Server Import and Export tool would likely be the easiest solution.